# All values in list become same as appended element

Tags: python, append

My desired data are values in the lists `n_ac` ,`n_bc` and `n_cd`, and I would like to append the three lists into other three lists called `copyn_ac`, `copyn_bc` and `copyn_cd` every time I calculate the desired data. However, I found that the value in `copyn_ac`, `copyn_bc` and `copyn_cd` becomes the values in the latest appended list and so all the values in `copyn_ac`, `copyn_bc` and `copyn_cd` end up becoming the same.

Here is part of my code(irrelevant code has been deleted for shorter post):

```
def copy ():
    print('Desired data:n_ac=',n_ac)
    print('Desired data:n_bc=',n_bc)
    print('Desired data:n_cd=',n_cd)
    copyn_ac.append(n_ac)
    copyn_bc.append(n_bc)
    copyn_cd.append(n_cd)

def display_copyn ():
    print('copyn_ac =', copyn_ac)
    print('copyn_bc =', copyn_bc)
    print('copyn_cd =', copyn_cd)

def start_1 (cell3):
    for c in cell3:
        c.save_n()
    for c in cell3:
        c.cal_init_val()
    for c in cell3:
        c.cal_alpha_S_R()
    for c in cell3:
        c.cal_y()

def start(cell3):
    checking()
    start_1(cell3)
    copy()

def update (cell1,cell2,cell3):
    checking()      ### From Here ###
    update_1(cell1)
    update_2(cell2) ### Calculate the desired data ###
    empty_list()
    update_3(cell3) ### To Here ###
    copy()  ### copy desired data into other list
```

When I run the program:

```
start(cell3)
display_copyn()
update(cell1,cell2,cell3)
display_copyn()
update(cell1,cell2,cell3)
display_copyn()
```

Output:

```
Desired data:n_ac= [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]
Desired data:n_bc= [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]
Desired data:n_cd= [70, 70, 70, 70, 70]
copyn_ac = [[33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]]
copyn_bc = [[36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]]
copyn_cd = [[70, 70, 70, 70, 70]]
Desired data:n_ac= [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]
Desired data:n_bc= [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]
Desired data:n_cd= [110.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0]
copyn_ac = [[33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334], [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]]
copyn_bc = [[36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666], [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]]
copyn_cd = [[110.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0], [110.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0]]
Desired data:n_ac= [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]
Desired data:n_bc= [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]
Desired data:n_cd= [150.0, 30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0]
copyn_ac = [[33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334], [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334], [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]]
copyn_bc = [[36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666], [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666], [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]]
copyn_cd = [[150.0, 30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0], [150.0, 30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0], [150.0, 30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0]]
```

The expected output after one start function and two update function:

```
copyn_ac = [[33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334], [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334], [33.33333333333334, 33.33333333333334]]
copyn_bc = [[36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666], [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666], [36.66666666666666, 36.66666666666666]]
copyn_cd = [[70, 70, 70, 70, 70],[110.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0],[150.0, 30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0]]
```

What should I do in order to get the expected output?

Update:
I made a minimal working code for my program and the same problem happen:

```
import numpy as np
data01=[]
copy_data=[]
class cell ():
    def __init__ (self,number, parameter,index, data=0):
        self.number = number
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.index = index
        self.data = data
    def cal_data(self):
        self.data = np.minimum(self.number,self.parameter)
        data01.append(self.data)
    def change_val(self):
        self.number = data01[self.index]*1.1*self.number
        self.parameter = data01[self.index]*1.2*self.parameter        

def save_data ():
    copy_data.append(data01)
def empty_list():
    del data01 [::]

c1 = cell(2,5,0)
c2 = cell(3,1,1)
cell_1 =[c1,c2]

def start01 (cell_1):
    for c in cell_1:
        c.cal_data()

def start (cell_1):
    start01(cell_1)
    save_data()
    print(copy_data)

def update01(cell_1):
    for c in cell_1:
        c.change_val()

def update02(cell_1):
    for c in cell_1:
        c.cal_data()

def update(cell_1):
    update01(cell_1)
    empty_list()
    update02(cell_1)
    save_data()
    print(copy_data)
```

Run the program:

```
start(cell_1)
update(cell_1)
update(cell_1)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1]]
[[4.4, 1.2], [4.4, 1.2]]
[[21.296000000000006, 1.728], [21.296000000000006, 1.728], [21.296000000000006, 1.728]]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but after changing to `copyn_cd.append(n_cd)` the output become `copyn_cd = [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 110.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 150.0, 30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0]` which `len(copyn_cd) =15` and it is slightly different compared to the expected output which has len(copyn_cd) = 3.

Comment: sorry.. can you post a minimal working code.

Comment: I have uploaded a minimal working code in the post, see whether it helps or not

Comment: how are you calling ```start(cell_1) ...```?  the minimal example is missing the calls to start()...

Comment: I have function `start(cell_1)` below the code of the function `start01(cell_1)` and  `start01(cell_1)` will run after `start(cell_1)` is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding the same instance of the list (`data01`) to the saved list (`copy_data`). So, when that instance changes, it affects all the copies of that list in the saved list. Think of `copy_data` as a collection of pointers, all pointing to the same actual list (`data01`).

To fix it:

```
def save_data ():
    copy_data.append(data01.copy())
    # copy_data.append(data01).   <== old code
```